# Why project reactor uses a power of 2 as concurrency buffer size?

Tags: project-reactor

Project reactor uses a power of 2 as its buffer size.

XS_BUFFER_SIZE defaults to 32 and SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE defaults to 256.

Why is that?

Is it recommended to use a power of 2 as flatMap concurrency?